# Dart - How to check if my list has same values for departmentId?

Tags: dart

For example I have list as:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> employees = [
  {"name": 'Kris', 'departmentId': 18, CityId: 1},
  {"name": 'Ana', 'departmentId': 18, CityId: 2},
  {"name": 'Monty', 'departmentId': 18, CityId: 3},
  {"name": 'John', 'departmentId': 18, CityId: 4},
];
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to verify that all entries has the same `departmentId` value?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `List`, and you want to make sure that all items in the list have a certain property, you can use `List.every`. For example:

```dart
bool isEven(int n) => n % 2 == 0;

[1, 2, 3, 4].every(isEven)  // false, some values are not even
[2, 4, 6, 8].every(isEven)  // true, every value is even
```

In your case, you can check that every value of `departmentId` has the same value as the first (if you don't know that id ahead of time).

```dart
bool allHaveSameDepartment(List<Map<String, dynamic>> employees) {
  bool sameIdAsFirst(Map<String, dynamic> employee) => employee['departmentId'] == employees[0]['departmentId'];
  return employees.every(sameIdAsFirst);
}
```

Note that in this case, an empty list will return `true` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). You may wish to override this behaviour by checking `employees.isEmpty` at the start and maybe throwing an error or returning false.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by using `toSet()`.

Solution: `employees.map((value) => value.departmentId).toSet().length`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your solution? It might be useful to others who have this problem if you explain why your solution works.